# MIPS: Size of .asciiz?

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32, spim

> When determining the size of .asciiz string, should I take into
> consideration the terminating character ?

For example:

```
.data
string: .asciiz "Hello"
```

The size of "string" is 5 or 6 (byte) ?

Comment: The size of the data includes the NULL byte at the end of the string, so it consumes 6 bytes. However, the length of the ASCIIZ string is 5 characters. I guess you want to know the space used, that would be 6 bytes.

Comment: @gusbro So it's 6 bytes. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are asking about how many bytes in memory the string is stored in then it's 6 bytes

if you are asking about what should be returned by a function that count the string length (strlen C function for example) it should be 5

Answer (score 1):

This particular asciiz string requires 6 bytes of storage.

In programming situations, you will measure the  string size to be 5.  As in `strlen()`.

When using this string, very likely, your loop will be testing for `NULL` conditions, and will run for 5 iterations.

When copying, storing this string, your code will likely loop 5 times, and then (outside of loop), add an extra NULL '\0' character at the end, to maintain `NULL` termination.  Therefore the destination storage space must be 1 more than `strlen()`.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Robert, in this case the bytes in memory total 6. As Paxym explains however, in high-level languages it will measure the string 'size' to be 5.

Answer (score -1):

Every character of ascii is 1 byte. if you write hello it is 5 byte