# MIPS ASCIIZ with \n bytes size?

Tags: mips

According the following link, the size of "Hello" is 6 because of the null at the end (because its ascii**z**).

[MIPS: Size of .asciiz?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127392/mips-size-of-asciiz)

But what would be the size of "Hello\n"

8 or 7?

is `\n` considered as 1 byte or 2 bytes?

Comment: Sounds like something you could easily test yourself in SPIM or MARS.

Answer (score 1):

This code gives you the length of the of arbitrary string.Using MARS-simulator it will gives you the length of `5` for  `Hello`
and `6` for `Hello\n`

This means that the size of `\n` is `1` byte and the size of `Hello\n` is `7` byte.

```
.data
    message: .asciiz "Hello\n"
.text

main:
    li $t1,0
    la $t0,message

loop:
    lb   $a0,0($t0)
    beqz $a0,done
    addi $t0,$t0,1
    addi $t1,$t1,1
    j     loop
done:

    li   $v0,1
    add  $a0, $0,$t1
    syscall

    li   $v0,10
    syscall
```